# Relational database normalization technique

Tags: database, database-normalization

[This](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:75zHzfbuQOQJ%3awww.atilim.edu.tr/~mrehan/Compe502-N3.pdf%20normalization%20student%20.tr&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESg396xR9TKacnW1OIQpDLAD4-YxjU8uAZ9osE6x28Z3r5D9OqgsvdcMVqrQEDpjpAm4ur1lO6GWaMp3hTxyOQTTRzZXsWZkc-Fq90vWEXJB1QdXCtEp2dILr66D_v7YJbD1TPQf&sig=AHIEtbQjS3P5VMFL2IJr69iUfDqjJ3qBQQ) pdf document is a lecture slide from a Turkish university.

Here the lecturer introduced a technique to normalize database data that seems to involve pen and paper (Page-3).

What does he mean by R1, R2, R3, etc... and FD1, FD2, FD3, etc...

Can anyone provide me with any reference supporting this technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R means "Relation" (think table schema) and FD means "Functional Dependency".

A [Functional Dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) describe what attributes "determine" other values *within a Relation*. By fully reducing the FDs the Candidate Keys are left (and *new* Relations may be exposed). One of these Candidate Keys will be the Primary Key. (Of course, it is common these days to just have a [Surrogate Primary Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) -- which is sometimes a subject of controversy -- and thus the Candidate Keys all become Secondary Keys).

Just from Wikipedia (which is a fairly good place to start), see [Relational Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model), [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [Boyce-Codd normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form). (Note that BCNF is not always possible depending upon the FDs.)

Happy coding.

---

It's been forever and I can't find my old textbook, but [Fundamentals of Database Systems: Functional Dependencies and Normalization for Relational Databases](http://www.scribd.com/doc/3113089/Chap10Functional-Dependencies-and-Normalization-for-Relational-Databases) seems more like a gentle primer -- it lacks on showing the application of the Armstrong's Rules though, from what an I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Normalization is a technique for building tables beginning from a set of data you need to store exploiting the relations between this data. Rn, then, are Tables on the database and FDn (Functional Dependencies) are the information you have on the fields that allow you to obtain the subset of fields that you can use for obtaining the rest (thus becoming Primary Keys and Foreign Keys on the database).

You can do normalization via an algorithm but since the data you need to compute is usually small (Not the data in the database. I mean the structure of the database.) it is better done on pen and paper during the database design phase.

Comment: FDn are functional dependencies, which are a kind of "relationship between fields", but wouldn't use that language in this context because it could lead to confusion.  "Relationship" is this context is usually meant to be between entities (the Rs).  The FDs have more to do with primary keys than with foreign keys.  FDs tell you which attributes "determine" or uniquely identify which other attributes.